# Get days to next date from one array to another in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have two arrays (data frames actually but the function below deals with arrays)

`bh_arr` = array of bank holiday dates in UK

`sales_dates` = Sales dates for a few years (millions of rows, I mean really millions)

I want to know for each date in `sales_dates`, how many days to the next bank holiday (from `bh_arr`).

I built a function like the below and it works but as is evident from the code it is very wasteful, as it calculates all differences first and then gets the non-negative min.

```
def get_days_to_bh_arr(sale_dates, bh_arr):

    """
    Subtract all elements of bh_arr from each element of sales_dates.
    Get the min ( > 0) for each element of sales_dates.
    Return that array.
    """
    bh_arr = pd.to_datetime(bh_arr)
    res = []

    for each in sale_dates:
        gg = int(np.min([stuff for stuff in (bh_arr - pd.to_datetime(each))/np.timedelta64(1,'D') if stuff >= 0]))
        res.append(gg)

    return np.array(res)
```

```
bh_arr = ['2018-03-30', '2018-08-27', '2019-05-27']
sales_dates = ['2018-03-15', '2019-05-22', '2018-02-01', '2018-08-05', '2018-06-21']

get_days_to_bh_arr(sale_dates, bh_arr)
```

`15, 5, 57, 22, 67`

In the actual code, I finally make the call like so:

`sales['days_to_next_bh'] = get_days_to_bh_arr(sales['full_date'], bh['holiday']).astype(np.int32)`

Is there a more efficient way of writing the function (of course there is)?

If not, should I try something else like finding the next date from a sorted 'bh_arr', for each date in 'sales_dates' and only at the end do the subtraction? How would I make that work?
Could I vectorise that instead of looping?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas this can be done with `pd.merge_asof` to bring the closest bank holiday in the future. Then datetime subtraction gets the days in between.

Because `merge_asof` requires sorting, we need to reset the index so that we can maintain the original ordering after the merge.

```
import pandas as pd

df_b = pd.DataFrame({'bh': pd.to_datetime(bh_arr)})
df_s = pd.DataFrame({'sd': pd.to_datetime(sales_dates)})

df_s = (pd.merge_asof(df_s.reset_index().sort_values('sd'), 
                      df_b.sort_values('bh'),
                      direction='forward',
                      left_on='sd',
                      right_on='bh')
          .sort_values('index'))

arr = (df_s['bh'] - df_s['sd']).dt.days.to_numpy()
#array([15,  5, 57, 22, 67], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: This is brilliant @ALollz ! For 10,815,172 rows using %%timeit in a notebook, it took `4.45 s ± 35.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)` which is insanely quicker than what I was doing before. Do you have any pointers on how it does it?

Comment: @BishS I'm not 100% sure of the pandas internals for this one. Because it requires sorting, my guess is it uses some kind of search sorted or partitioning to quickly figure out the proper value to insert.

Comment: No worries, thanks again, I'll check the docs and the source. Was just curious.